# Oem unlock failed- fastboot

Tags: fastboot

What's the reason for oem unlock failed? I searched a lot, couldn't find an answer.

Comment: fastboot flashing get_unlock_ability

Comment: `oem unlock`  is as the command implies an OEM command which means it is manufacturer specific if it is implemented and how it works. A lot of devices don't have this command at all. Make sure it is really supported by your device.

Comment: @alecxs as i mentioned my device  bootloader is unlocked now. So ```get_unlock_ability``` should be true/1

Comment: I am sorry but your question is very confusing please state exactly what you are trying to do, what command(s) you execute and what result/errors you get for each command.

Comment: No prob :) Edited my question

Comment: so we went from unlock failed to how flash custom rom? not only headline is misleading but also your comments. Why do you want unlock bootloader if bootloader is unlocked already? if partition *system* doesn't exist you probably should flash it to existing target (like *system_a*) or use `fastbootd` (dynamic partitions)

Comment: @alecxs  Apology if you got me wrong. I edited because Robert found my description confusing and asked me to clarify things. My question is still the same. In edited and unedited part, I used total 3 "?". All of which are about ``` OEM unlock failed``` . Your reply was helpful too :)  I will use ```fastbootd``` I think.

Comment: I also used ```fastboot flash a_file.img```  which produced error - oem unlock failed unlike  ```fastboot flash system hsjsj.img ``` which give partition error. I noticed ```fastboot flash something``` produce oem unlock failed error, that's why I wrote "if I try to flash.........." In 3rd line.

Comment: please read Robert's 1st comment - there is no error and nothing to fix. furthermore can't see  *"flash something produce oem unlock failed error"* on your screenshot - are you sure about that?

Comment: It's my 2nd time unblocking this devious. Previous time when I unlocked the bootloader "fastboot oem unlock" worked. This time I'm getting error. My screenshot was about partition error which I posted   in a gsi group to get help. Added here to reference step 8. Also it contains the oem unlock failed error.

Comment: This post is getting messier and perhaps out of topic. I guess I need to improve "how to ask".... After Robert read  I will remove the edited parts and also improve and shorter my description to make it more cleaner. Can you answer why  error- Oem unlock failed occur in general? Thanks a bunch to both of you for your replays and time :)

Comment: *fastboot flashing unlock* is the official command. *fastboot **oem** unlock* is something only [oem](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-discover-hidden-fastboot-commands) knows how it works. if bootloader is unlocked already that is probably the reason why it fails (you won't ask your mom to open the door if it is already open, or she would give you an error on that command at least) I barely see the relation between flashing failed and oem unlock failed if your bootloader is unlocked already

Comment: I'm not asking about the behaviour of fastboot oem unlock. Or anything particularly about oem.I'm asking about error- Oem unlock failed. I get this from  multiple commands. Anyway I am closing and removing the edited parts.

Comment: you get *"error- oem unlock failed" [...] "from multiple commands"*?? which command(s) exactly (others than *fastboot oem unlock*)!? what error exactly!?

Comment: Question closed as per OP's attempt to close their own question but the vote expired.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `OEM Unlock` enabled under Developer settings from your phone.
And also install `Android Bootloader drivers` on windows. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35076765/942317